# Java - Quartz CronSchedule doesn't Work with start date and end date

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

When I set the startDate and endDate to Trigger, the ChronSchedule call the execute method on the job only once.

```
JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(service)
                    .withIdentity(batchService.getName(), CommonConstants.BATCH_JOB_GROUP).build();
            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                    .newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity(batchService.getName(), CommonConstants.BATCH_JOB_GROUP)
                    .startAt(startDate)
                    .endAt(endDate)
                    .withSchedule(
                            CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?"))
                    .build();
            System.out.println("##########" + trigger.getEndTime());
            System.out.println("##########" + trigger.getStartTime());
```

As you can see I put some print on trigger for getting start date and end date. 
It seems correct:

```
##########Fri Oct 20 16:00:00 CEST 2017
##########Fri Oct 20 15:00:00 CEST 2017
```

In the execute method, I put a print:

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException
    {   
        System.out.println("Executing job. The next: " + context.getNextFireTime());

    }
```

but the result is unconfortable:

```
Executing job. The next: null
```

What have I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about CronsScheduler or CronsTrigger but you can try following instead of CronScheduleBuilder.

import org.quartz.* Packages.

```
JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(MYJOB.class).withIdentity(jobName).withDescription("TryThis").build();

CalendarIntervalTriggerImpl trigger = new CalendarIntervalTriggerImpl("triggername", startTime, endTime,
                                 DateBuilder.IntervalUnit.valueOf("MINUTE"), frequency);

// Try to keep scheduler object as singultant object. 
// OR it'll also work fine if you start scheduler it multiple times with diffrebt scheduler object for JDBCJob store.

SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(); 

Scheduler scheduler = sf.getScheduler();  
scheduler.start();

scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```